# Jquery validator allow only specific array of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that using jquery validator we can allow specific characters in a textbox while validating form.

Is it possible that jquery validator should not allow specific array of strings. We can't write plenty of lines to check whether equal or not. 
Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: Do you have a list of characters that you dont want to allow?

Comment: yeah it may be anything like 'cj,sj,rf,rrf,mgf,tgd,etc.,'